# Non-Admin Roles Cannot Delete Custom Posts

Tags: php, wordpress

We have a site that has custom roles. These roles (trial, member) have been granted the capabilities `delete_posts` and `delete_published_posts`.

We then use a simple link to allow users to delete their own posts:

```
<a onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this scanner?')" class="btn btn-outline-danger w-100" href="<?php echo get_delete_post_link( $post->ID ) ?>">Delete Custom Scanner</a>
```

Unfortunately, this only works for admins. For any other users, it redirects to the home page without deleting the post.

Does anyone know what is incorrect here? Thank you!

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_delete_post_link/#comment-4584: _"Be careful, if you use this function with a custom post type, you must define the “show_ui” parameter of the register_post_type() function to true."_ (user comment)

Comment: Thanks, but as far as I can tell, it is set to true!

Comment: What capabilities was the CPT registered with, and which ones do the users in question have? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/#capabilities